# Why was JavaFX event handling designed such that we must create an instance of the class holding the handle() method?

Tags: javafx

In JavaFx, I understand that if I want a button to make some code run when it is clicked, I need to somehow have the code that I want to have run inside a method, and because this is Java, I wrap that method inside a class that extends EventHandler . For example:

```
// (myButton is a reference variable to a Button object)
myButton.setOnAction(new MyButtonEventHandlerClass() );

// inner class
public class MyButtonEventHandlerClass extends EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
  public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    // (some code)
  }
}
```

My confusion is: why is JavaFX designed to require me to make an instance of the class holding the handle() method? I had thought that non-static methods are used when the instance variables of an object are used; or in other words, if you just need a method that does not need an object, then you should use a static method. In this kind of thinking, handle() sounds like it should be a static method.

Why is handle() not a static method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criteria for a `EventHandler` to work in a meaningful way in this case are:

1. There needs to be some way to store the information.
2. The information has to be stored in a way that allows more than one way of dealing with a event.

Now regardless of the `handle` method actually using any fields in the `EventHandler`and/or enclosing classes, there needs to be a way do identify the code that should handle the event.
If `handle` only was a `static` method, there only would ever be a single handler which even worse would be determined by the JavaFX programmers, since `static` methods cannot be overridden. It would not be possible to fulfil condition `2.` without a non-`static` method.

For non-static methods however it's pretty simple to deal with this. Methods can be overridden and handling the event the correct way can simply be done by invoking `EventHandler.handle` for the event handler object.

---

In java 8 however method references (or lambda expressions) could be used to shorten this a bit by using method references, which allows you to "use a method as interface instance":

```
public class MyClass {

     public static void handleMyButtonAction(ActionEvent evt) {
         // (some code)
     }

}
```

```
myButton.setOnAction(MyClass::handleMyButtonAction);
```

Comment: ah, i didn't realize that non-static methods cannot be overridden. thanks!